# Problems aligning ImageButton within LinearLayout?

Tags: android, xml, layout, alignment, android-linearlayout

This is my code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
android:background="@drawable/game_background"
android:weightSum="100"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" android:layout_weight="70"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="228dp">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30px" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Version 0.0.0.1"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>


            <TextView
                android:text="Thanks for trying out the very first version of this program!\n\n"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:textColor="#000000"></TextView>


            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/prefs_exit" android:onClick="exit_button"
                android:background="#00000000"></ImageButton>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <ImageButton android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/prefs_exit" android:onClick="exit_button"
                android:background="#00000000"></ImageButton>


        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is the image button in the second linearLayout comes on the right side of the screen instead of at the bottom :(

How do I fix this?

And finally, I want to put a graphic (a logo) on the total bottom, right corner side.

Note, I am a newbie and still very much learning this... just got lost via the examples.

Thanks!
Ryan

Comment: try adding **android:orientation="vertical"** to the first LinearLayout

Comment: Yay! That worked! But its not at the right bottom, its a little way up :( Now how do I add the logo to the right? Also please write your comment as an answer so I can pick your answer!

Comment: Ok, I solved it via Sam Quests help (except logo to right) but since this was not in the form of an answer, what do I do now as I cannot award this to him?

Comment: Use RelativeLayout instead of LinearLayout.Using Relative layout you can set button easily where you want to set

Comment: @Dharmendra, I did use relative layouts everywhere else but according to my tutorial scrollview only works in this layout... so did it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding `android:orientation="vertical"` to the first **LinearLayout**

**UPDATE**

as for logo to the right, try `android:gravity="right"` in your second **LinearLayout**

Answer (score 1):

Here is your correct layout, just check it and just replace the background images with your images. Have fun developing applications.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
            android:layout_height="228dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                android:layout_height="30px"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Version 0.0.0.1"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>

                <TextView
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:text="Thanks for trying out the very first version of this program!\n\n"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></TextView>

                <ImageButton
                    android:src="@drawable/icon"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#00000000"
                    android:onClick="exit_button"
                    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageButton>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout02"
                    android:layout_weight="30"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:src="@drawable/icon"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:background="#00000000"
                        android:onClick="exit_button"
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"></ImageButton>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```